# "By 2013, computers will increase in power by 50 to 100 times." - Science Channel (Brink)

Tags: cpu

At about the 2:34 mark in [this](http://science.discovery.com/videos/brink-package-artificial-intelligence-arrives.html) video (from the science channel) the interviewer says that "By 2013, some experts predict computers will increase in power by 50 to 100 times."

Is that even possible?  Which experts are they referring to?  That seems like a huge leap in just a few years time.

Comment: perhaps with greater GPU (paralell processing) integration it could be.  I however am only using like 5% of this machines resources already... and so are most people.

Answer (score 2):

I usually disregard all the articles that refer to "experts" as such ...

And what is computing power ? Actual power of your power unit ? Instructions per second ? FLOPS ? Speed of single cores, or of processors in whole ?